# Автоимпорт в vscode. Есть ли расширение?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так работает на данный момент топовое расширение в vscode. В webstorm есть очень классная функция автоимпортирования. Там или само вставляется или в случае чего нужные слова подчеркиваются, это означает что их нужно импортировать и сделать это можно просто при помощи вроде alt + еще 2 клавишы, и все необходимые импорты сразу вставляются на всей странице за раз. Я перешел на VSCode, и хотелось бы ее тоже. Я поискал среди библиотеки но там один нормальный автоимпорт, но он импортирует уж очень слабо, если копипастишь код, ничего не светиться что требует импорта, нужно самому наводить курсор на последий символ того элемента что ты хочешь импортнуть, удалять его и писать заново тот самый удаленный символ, чтобы сработала подсказка и можно жать enter что даст тот самый импорт. Про к примеру библиотеку react-bootstrap вообще не находит, приходится ручками писать каждый импорт. Есть что получше у кого?

Comment: В VSCode - это тупая проблема, спасибо разработчикам. Почему они не пофиксили это дело - неясно. Лично мое мнение - это полный бред.